# Ordering a top ten query

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

Thanks for reading.

I'm trying to write a query to list the names of people who have recevied the most votes using two tables:

```
-------
votes
-------
vote_id, giver_user_id, receiver_user_id, datetime
```

etc..

```
-------
users
-------

user_id, name, surname
```

etc...

So far I have:

```
$top_query = "SELECT * FROM vote, user WHERE vote.receiver_user_id = user.user_id GROUP BY receiver_user_id  ";
```

This kind of works, but it doesn't list the user with the most votes at the top of the list.

How can I order it this way?

Thank you.

OP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  u.*, COUNT(vote_id) AS votes_count
FROM    users u
LEFT JOIN
        votes v
ON      v.receiver_user_id = u.user_id
GROUP BY
        u.user_id
ORDER BY
        votes_count DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ORDER BY clause.
With the keyword "asc" or "desc"

Something like :

```
ORDER BY vote_count DESC
```

Mysql reference :

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html

Answer (score 0):

This will group by receiver and order by votes in descending order:

```
    select receiver_user_id, count(1) vote_count
      from vote, user 
     where vote.receiver_user_id = user.user_id 
  group by receiver_user_id 
  order by 2 desc
```